# React Router - Empty Page, page not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am using React. I am using class Components.
I am also using React Router.

Here is my code:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
 }

 handleCreateComponent = () =>{
    return this.props.history.push('/app/pages/pageA/new');
 }

 render = () =>{
    return(
    <div>
        <div>
             <Button id="addComponent" onClick={this.handleCreateComponent}>ButtonA</Button>

        </div>
     </div>
);
}
```

**My Question:**

When I click "ButtonA", it navigates to the link: /app/pages/pageA/new
However, the page is empty and not displaying anything even though it's supposed to render.

What might be the problem ?

Comment: can you post the code for that page?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you've an issue with. In other words, what is rendering the page you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `<Link to="/app/pages/pageA/new"/>` or `<NavLink to="/app/pages/pageA/new"/>` from the `react-router` instead of `<Button/>`

But the rendering problem might be something else. in your question you say `/api/pages/pageA/new`  but in the code it's `'/app/pages/pageA/new'`

Comment: This is a great comment regarding Link vs Button but doesn't really address the issue of the page not rendering. OP hasn't provided enough context to provide any valuable answer.